# Polymer 0.8: How observe changes in objects member of an array property

Tags: polymer, web-component, observers

In a polymer 0.8 component, I have an array property:

```
properties: {
  myarr: {type: Array, observer: 'myObserver'}
}
```

When I assign the array `component.myarr = [{myobject1}, {myobject2}]`, the observer is called, but I want another method to be called when `myobject` inside the array is modified `myarr[0].foo = 'bar'`

I would like to use Polymer observations so as I don't have to load 3party polyfills for browsers non implementing Object.observe